# Independent ROS packages

Tags: c++, ros

Let's suppose I have a ROS metapackage A with some messages and other metapackage B with other messages. Is it possible to communicate A with B with msgs mechanism without making dependencies of each other? My aim is to let user clone metapackage A and build it totally independently of package B and symmetrically clone package B and build it independently of package A and with starting specific node allow to communicate them with some complex message. Is it even possible?

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

Let's say package A uses a message type that is defined in package B. In order to use this message type, you need to include the generated header file, which is only possible if you add B as a dependency of A.

There are two solutions I can think of (whether they are feasible for you, I don't know):

1. You could move all the message definitions of A and B to a separate package C (which only contains the messages and nothing more). A and B have then to depend on this new package C but have no dependencies between each other.
2. Another solution might be to use only standard message types that are already defined by ros. This is of course only a feasible solution, if the data you're sending fits in one of the standard message types.

Comment: I already use the first solution that you mentioned. It's clean and compact, but I'm "code purist" and was hoping there is some other mechanism.

Since my first metapackage I want to make public and second one is only for my personal purposes We (whole group) have decided to put message in the same form in both metapackages. It allows contributors to use those messages as a output of first metapackage and if I want to build both projects I just add CATKIN_IGNORE to one of message nodes and everything works like a charm.

Thanks anyway!